# After the PSID-Migration, will the PSID remain same for a User across different Apps[Same Page]?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, scope-id

As per the facebook guidelines all the Reviewed Apps to be migrated from ASID(App Scope ID) to PSID(Page Scope ID).
This is the warning displayed on my dashboard.

> Migration Required by Jan 16, 2019. Apps that do not migrate by the deadline will be automatically migrated.

Since we can select the Primary App and secondary app for a page, will the PSID remain same in both the Apps?

For Example, let's take this Example

- Lets Consider user as : *X*
- We have 2 Apps: *App1* and *App2*
- We have a page: *Page1* [Associated with both *App1* and *App2*]

Now My Question is:

> Will the user *X* have same PSID across the Apps *App1* and *App2* for this particular page *Page1*?

Comment: If that was not the case, calling it _page-scoped_ would not make sense to begin with …

Comment: I totally agree. I need more details regarding this as I need to change/alter code for the App(its live).
I would have tested this on G-API but the test app also requires Review Process in order to fetch end-user detail. I also want to know about the structure of the PSID because another thread says this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192810/are-facebook-messenger-page-scoped-ids-globally-unique